# Does the sequence ${1\over n}\{x_{mn+1}+x_{mn+2}+ \cdots +x_{2mn-1}+x_{2mn}\}$, where $m\in \mathbb{Z^+}$, converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ converges to $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Does the sequence ${1\over n}\{x_{mn+1}+x_{mn+2}+ \cdots +x_{2mn-1}+x_{2mn}\}$, where $m\in \mathbb{Z^+}$, converge?

I was solving convergence of sequences and this problem has come up. I am unable to get started. Please help me solving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried doing here?

Comment: Is $n$ the variable and $m$ a fixed integer?

Comment: @ Dionel: $n $ is variable and $m$is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a classic result that if $(x_n) $ converges to $L$ then $$\frac{x_1 + \dots + x_n}{n} \to L $$

If you don't know this, then try proving it. From this we can conclude both
$$\frac{x_1 +  \dots + x_{2mn} }{2mn}  \ \ \text{and} \ \  \frac{x_1 \dots + x_{mn}}{mn} $$

converge to $L$. Multiplying the left term above by $2$ and then subtracting the right term, we obtain

$$\frac{x_{mn+1} + \dots + x_{2mn} }{mn} \to L $$

Multiplying by $m$ gives the desired result.